# MySQL Creating Stored Procedure to compare two values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried creating a stored procedure from the question below but when I test it using the values from my tables in my database, it is not giving me the correct output. Meaning if it should output 1, it outputs 2 instead.
Please help me figure what I did wrong.
Question and my sql statement is below.

Question: Create a stored procedure to compare the actual incomes of two employees. If the former is higher than the latter, output 1; otherwise, output 2.

```
Delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE real_income(in employeeID_1 varchar(6), in employeeID_2 varchar(6),
out c int)
BEGIN
IF (SELECT income-outcome FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_1)>
(SELECT income-outcome FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_2) THEN SET c = 1;
ELSE SET c = 2;
END IF;
END $$
```

[Sample data from salary table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx6NB.png)

Comment: sample data? table structure? how can we answrer without?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You selection for the column is bad as mysql interprets it a subtraction of two columns.
So use backticks, or rename it

> ```
> CREATE TABLE salary(employeeID INT,`income-outcome` DECIMAL(10,2))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO salary VALUEs (1,10.2),(2,20.2)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE real_income(in employeeID_1 varchar(6), in employeeID_2 varchar(6),
> out c int)
> BEGIN
> IF (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_1)>
> (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_2) THEN SET c = 1;
> ELSE SET c = 2;
> END IF;
> END
> ```

> ```
> CALL real_income(1,2,@i)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT @i
> ```
>
> ```
> | @i |
> | -: |
> |  2 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=752f16501859b5672347fd69b911c296)*

A better solution is this, so you can also check for equality

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE real_income(in employeeID_1 varchar(6), in employeeID_2 varchar(6),
> out c int)
> BEGIN
> SET c = (CASE WHEN (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_1)>
> (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_2) THEN  1
> WHEN (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_1) =
> (SELECT `income-outcome` FROM salary WHERE employeeID=employeeID_2) THEN  0
> ELSE  2 END);
>
> END
> ```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. Really appreciate it